# Send csv files with data from db to email python

Tags: python, jquery, django, database, csv

I have db and there is table called Users.

| id | name | last_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Black | active |
| 2 | Drake | Bell | disabled |
| 3 | Pep | Guardiola | active |
| 4 | Steve | Salt | disabled |

I would like to send to one email two csv files.
The first one will be with name **sucess.csv** and ther**e will be ID from the table, with status active, and the second one csv will be named** failed.csv and inside will be ID with status disabled.
Right now my code looks like this:

```
def send_user_report():
    logger.info('User report generating')

    user_data = {}
    user = Users.objects.values('id', 'status')

    buffer = io.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(buffer)

    writer.writerow([])
    

 
    email = EmailMessage('Users report', body, to=settings.EMAIL_TEST)
    email.attach('sucess_report.csv', buffer.getvalue(), 'text/csv')
    email.send()
```

Comment: And what is your issue?

Comment: I dont understand how send two separate csv depending of status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write to two attachments:

```
def send_user_report():
    logger.info('User report generating')

    user_data = {}
    user = Users.objects.values('id', 'status')

    buffer = io.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(buffer)
    for user in Users.objects.filter(status='active')
        writer.writerow([user.pk])
    
    buffer2 = io.StringIO()
    writer2 = csv.writer(buffer2)
    for user in Users.objects.filter(status='disabled')
        writer2.writerow([user.pk])
    
    email = EmailMessage('Users report', '', to=settings.EMAIL_TEST)
    email.attach('sucess_report.csv', buffer.getvalue(), 'text/csv')
    email.attach('failed_report.csv', buffer2.getvalue(), 'text/csv')
    email.send()
```